# What's the relative phase between current, voltage and electric field in a receiving dipole antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, harmonic-oscillator, dipole, antennas

To help keep the question simple, please assume a half wavelength dipole at resonance such as in the image below:

[image]

I have been thinking about this problem using the analogy of a harmonic oscillator: the electric field applies a force to charge carriers, causing them to accelerate. The maximum velocity of charge carriers (in the center of the dipole) should therefore lag the the electric field, by 90 degrees, and I am assuming that current would be directly proportional to the charge carrier velocity (is this correct?). Finally, voltage across the ends of the dipole will reach a maximum when the charge carriers have been displaced the maximum amount from their starting position. So you have charge acceleration in phase with electric field, velocity in phase with current and position in phase with voltage. This suggests current (through centre) 90 degrees out of phase with electric field and voltage (across ends of antenna) an additional 90 degrees.

Is this way of thinking correct? If not, what are the phase relationships between E-field, current and voltage?